# How do I use the redtape gem? - Looking for a clearer usage example/sample

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nested-forms, model-associations

**Question: Does anyone out there have a simple example of how to use the redtape gem? I'm hoping for basic MVC examples that show me how it all comes together.**

**A different but related question: What other stuff might need to be done to get this up and running, but that isn't listed in the Readme.md description? What things might be assumed by the gem owner that a novice (like me) might not know to do?**

**NOTE:** I allude to "errors" here, but don't post them because I'm pretty sure they're not relevant. I don't think the particular errors I'm seeing are meaningful because I don't even think I'm doing the basics correctly to get this working.

**I'm pretty sure the redtape gem is what I need**

I'm looking for good alternatives to accepts_nested_attributes_for (ANAF), and it seems like the [redtape gem](https://github.com/ClearFit/redtape) is a popular choice for this sort of thing. (For history, see these two questions I've posted previously: [Rails 3.2 app - Should I use a versioning gem (paper_trail or vestal_versions) or handle it manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235524/rails-3-2-app-should-i-use-a-versioning-gem-paper-trail-or-vestal-versions-o) and [Rails - How to manage nested attributes without using accepts_nested_attributes_for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648396/rails-how-to-manage-nested-attributes-without-using-accepts-nested-attributes).)

**But I'm too dumb to use it - I don't know what I don't know**

My problem is I'm too ignorant to actually use the gem by following the included documentation. Normally, I would stumble into this sort of solution via a [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) episode (like [#196 Nested Model Form (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) that initially pointed me to ANAF before I realized ANAF isn't robust enough for what I'm doing), so I'd have found this option by just following a prepared guide. In this case, there's no Railscast, so I'm sort of stuck.

**Here's what I *have* done**

I have the gem installed, and I've tried using the sample code provided in the readme, but that's as far as I've gotten. Every time I try to actually use it, I've get a host of errors ("...redtape_path doesn't exist", various data-type errors) that seem to change as I monkey with my controller code. But I think the bigger problem is I have no idea what I'm doing and I'm just trying to hack something together.

For example (from the Readme.md):

```
//The form...

<%= form_for @form, :as => :whatever %>
...

# The controller
class SomethingController
  def new
    @form = Redtape::Form.new(self, params)
  end

  def create # should support update as well...
    @form = Redtape::Form.new(self, params)
    if @form.save
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

**What I think I need**

Has anyone out there actually used redtape, and could you share an example that shows all the moving parts (MVC)? I get the sense that I'm missing something big. I basically mimmicked the example with no luck at all (just error after error). Is there something else I'm missing? Do I need a "Something" model that is a Form object? What's that look like?

Note that I've also seen this post - [7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) - which seems helpful (Point 3. seems like it is probably very relevant), but I still don't know enough to utilize what I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote redtape. Though, as the README indicates, the Form object isn't my idea at all.  Actually, it wasn't Bryan Helmkamp's (sp?) either though his blog post inspired me to emulate and automate his particular technique.  The first time I remember seeing it was in Apache Struts back in '99, I think.

I **tried** to make redtape easy to use.  That said, the one time since I wrote it for ClearFit, I ran into a problem using it.  I didn't have time to diagnose it (as it was a tiny project in a big hurry) but it may have been an unexpected interaction with simple_form.

In any event, for a typical ANAF situation, you should be able to just pass your nested params to `Redtape::Form.new`. The returned `Form` object let's you either call `#save` and let Redtape handle persistence for you or you can extract the top of the object graph with `#model`.  IIRC, `Form` exposes validation errors as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is pretty helpful. First, I AM using simple_form for that form (although I think I tried it with a straight form_for also), so I'll double check that. Any chance you can share some sample MVC code from an instance where you've used redtape? It might help me to see what you have actually set up in a real application. If all you have is proprietary stuff, I understand that too. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I seem to consistently get this error - any idea what I'm missing here? Do I need a route for redtape?

undefined method `redtape_forms_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff25a78a240>:0x007ff25f392368>

Comment: And I should say that's happening on the first line of my form:

<%= form_for form, :as => :checklist do |f| %>

And I'm executing the ChecklistsController#New action:

  def new
    form = Redtape::Form.new(self, params)
 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: form }
    end
  end

...I can't use at-Form because of limitations of SO's comments (it thinks I'm mentioning someone named "Form"). So "Form" is actually "@Form" in the above snippet.

Comment: Try using your top-level model (whatever you're creating/updating an instance of) in your form_for instead of redtape.  Use redtape in the controller action.

Comment: Sadly, it's been several months since I've written the gem and the single working example that I have of redtape is in a proprietary code base that I no longer have access to...

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do. Thanks again!

Comment: I may've hit a snag with the gem. I try to save my Redtape::Form object, get an error "can't convert Symbol into Integer".

Traces to model_factory.rb line 82:

redtape (1.0.2) lib/redtape/model_factory.rb:82:in `[]'

Line 82:

root_object_id = attrs.values.first[:id]

This is in a "create" method, so there's no :id in the params hash (as there would be for an update action).

Controller lines:

  def create
    @form = Redtape::Form.new(self, params)
    if @form.save #Here's where it's choking

If I'm out of line here, I apologize. Thought you might want this in case you want to investigate.

Comment: Ah, But line 83 checks to see if <code>attr.values.first[:id]</code>returned a non-<code>nil</code> value.  That is, when you call [](key) on a Hash, if the key doesn't exist, it returns <code>nil</code>.  If it's <code>nil</code> then line 86 creates a new instance of the model class.  So I don't believe that's a bug.  That's not to say that there aren't bugs.  redtape is still fairly untried outside of my past client's project so I wouldn't be surprised.